# Coloring $[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, integration, coloring

Here is an interesting coloring problem that I am unable to prove. Any help is appreciated.

> Can we partition the closed interval $[0,1]$ into finitely many intervals, such that each sub-interval is colored red or blue in an alternating fashion, so that $$\int_{\text{red}}P(x)dx=\int_{\text{blue}}P(x)dx$$ for all polynomials $P$ with a fixed degree $n$?